# NUnit tests inconclusive after moving parameterized TestFixture to base class. Why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nunit

I have a test class that looks something like this:

```
[TestFixture("HomeAddress")]
[TestFixture("WorkAddress")]
[TestFixture("VacationAddress")]
public class AddressTests : BaseAddressTests
{
  private string _address;

  public AddressTests(string address)
  {
    _address = address;
  }

  // Tests here ...
}
```

These work all fine.  When I click *Run All* in my Visual Studio 2012 all the tests are run.  However, if I move the `TestFixture`s to the base class (here the silly `BaseAddressTests`) the tests all run inconclusive.

The only way I have found around this is to restart Visual Studio.  Then they all work again.  What is this all about?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the NUnit test adapter to run NUnit tests from within vs 2012... Does it work correctly if you use the NUnit GUI? If yes, then it might be a bug - search the NUnit discuss/develop mailing list..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the NUnit test adapter to run NUnit tests from within vs 2012... Does it work correctly if you use the NUnit GUI? If yes, then it might be a bug - search the NUnit discuss/develop mailing list.

[Update]
Resharper bundles in its own runner - as a result, the middle of the path (most used) features work but  the 'off-road' features don't work perfectly with it.

Comment: I am normally using Resharper’s test runner. I have tried to provoke the fault with both NUnit GUI and NCrunch‘s test runner, both of these run the tests perfectly. So it looks like there is a bug in Resharper’s test runner that results in this behavior.